# Excel formula to return different results for all cells equal to, blank or count of a value

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, formula

I am trying to create a formula that will look at a column of cells and do the following;

- if all cells blank then return no value
- if some cells "Unapproved" then count and show the number of these
- if all cells "Approved" then return "All Approved"

This is as far as got but will appreciate any help.  This is an array; =IF(ISBLANK(AD14:AD23)," ",CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(AD14:AD23,"Unapproved")," Awaiting Approval"))

Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I should add that there won't be any fixed amount of Approved or Unapproved values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Approved")=ROWS($AD$14:$AD$23),"All approved",IF(COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Unapproved"),COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Unapproved"),IF(COUNTBLANK($AD$14:$AD$23)=ROWS($AD$14:$AD$23),"","undefined return value")))
```

If your *blank* cells are actually empty string literals (""), returned by formulas then I would update to:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Approved")=ROWS($AD$14:$AD$23),"All approved",IF(COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Unapproved"),COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,"Unapproved"),IF(COUNTIF($AD$14:$AD$23,TEXT(,))=ROWS($AD$14:$AD$23),"","undefined return value")))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Thats very helpful.  Unfortunately it always returned 'undefined return value' even if there was just 'Approved' in the column.  So I changed it around a bit and it works, but it shows 'All Approved' if the column is blank.  Do you have any suggestions for changes to this formula to get it to return blank if no values in the column?  =IF(COUNTIF(AE14:AE23,"Approved")=COUNTA(AE14:AE23),"All Approved",IF(COUNTIF($AE$14:$AE$23,"Unapproved"),CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(AE14:AE23,"Unapproved")," Awaiting Approval"),""))

Comment: The formula works for what you described. If there is a single Approved it will default to undefined return value as you haven't specified what you want when not all blanks or not all approved or 1 or more unapproved. Leave all blank and you should get "". Add 1 or more unapproved and you should get count, add approved in all cells and you should get All Approved. Try those first with my formula. Does it work as expected?

Comment: I tried it again to be sure but any number of 'Approved' returns 'undefined return value' but it does a count on the 'Unapproved'.

Comment: You are doing some thing wrong or somehow I am misunderstanding you. Let me share a workbook.

Comment: Hello.  I get 404 page not found to that link?  Can you try another?

Comment: Sorry it didn't I don't know why.  But this is working now thanks to the prompt from your suggestion =IF(COUNTIF($AE$14:$AE$23,"Approved")=COUNTA($AE$14:$AE$23),"All Approved",IF(COUNTIF($AE$14:$AE$23,"Unapproved"),CONCATENATE(COUNTIF($AE$14:$AE$23,"Unapproved")," Awaiting Approval"),""))

Comment: ok. You see to changed your requirements as you are no longer counting all blanks and have added an Awaiting Approval return result.  But if you got where you needed to be yey.

Comment: But issue I have now is that the cells it is looking at, contain formulas which are normally blank, i.e. =IF(AD14=0," ","Unapproved") and it effects the formula.  It counts them and returns a value.  I need to find out how to ignore this formula.

Comment: oh... you didn't tell me the cells contain formulas! Do they all contain formulas? And when you say blank did you mean = "" ?